# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: express, authentication, token

I got the following error when trying to run my app `Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]`

I have this error because of this:

```
app.get( "/data",
    request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=xxxxxxx'),  
    function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body);
})
```

I'm passing the token with a middleware but I've just hardcoded it for the example.

What does this error mean? Is this something expected by the Google API?

Comment: what does `request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=xxxxxxx')` return ? see: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: what do you mean? It is supposed to return a JSON object

Comment: the second parameter is supposed to be a function. see the link I posted on the previous comment.

Comment: so I need to pass my function within a function... could you share a code example?

Comment: There's a really clear example in the link above ^^^

Comment: I tried something but I have a different kind of error now... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278362/request-with-express-not-returning-anything-infinite-load